# Java 8 doesn't compile on Intellij15

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8

Recently our company moved to Java 8 (previously working with Java 7).
Everything was fine while I was using Eclipse, but now I switched to IntelliJ Idea 15 (it's my first time in IntelliJ Idea) and it simply won't compile any Java 8 code (lambdas, etc.)

I searched for a solution and found out that I have to set a project language level to 8 in IntelliJ project settings, but it still doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: After changing the project level, try restarting the IDE and rebuilding the project

Comment: It would be better to provide a question with the specific errors you are seeing.

Comment: I get that its a neewb question, but its a mistake anyone could make and doesn't deserve the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you correctly selected the JDK.

In IntelliJ you should go to: `File -> Project Structure... project settings tab`, and make sure the project SDK points to the location of your java 8 JDK, (something like: `C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_45`)

And, of course, make sure the project language level is set to `8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`

Comment: Thanks, the JDK was set to java 7, indeed :)