# "variable is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final" error

Tags: java, oop, intellij-idea, inner-classes, final

I've got this error while trying to use a local member of one class in inner class inside.
I know that declare it as final will solve the issue but I read that Java 8 should handle it automaticlly, I'm using Intellij with Java 8 and it still does not compile.
Is there any other way to fix it without declare it as final?
thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to declare it final?

Comment: migrate to level 8 edit project structure

Comment: Saman- I already did. Andy- I need it to my university hw and I'm not sure if the instructors want us to use it. if there isn't any nicer way so I assume that thay will accept it.

Comment: @RonShemesh put your code here please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that declare it as final will solve the issue but I read that Java 8 should handle it automatically.

Java 8 will handle it if the variable is *effectively final*.

I can think of two possible explanations:

1. Maybe the variable is not *effectively final*.  Try explicitly declaring it as `final`.  If you get a compilation error (e.g. saying that something is trying to modify the `final`) then the variable isn't effectively final.
2. Maybe you haven't configured Intellij and the project properly for Java 8; e.g.

   - Set the source level; see @saman's answer
   - Check you have the right JDK selected: [Java 8 doesn't compile on Intellij15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471867/java-8-doesnt-compile-on-intellij15)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change your language level from "Project Structure" -> "Module" -> "your project name" -> "Source" -> "Language Level" and set it to 8

[image]